# App Dev ::Windows 8::how to provide news updates

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am trying to build a Sports App for Windows Store .I am not able to understand how am I suppose to change the data day on day. The App initially will have some static content and the data has to be updated daily. Kindly guide me how to do this , since this is my first App for windows store.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the data on a server somewhere. So use the HttpClient control to access the data, use Linq/XML to parse it, and then load it in your UI however you've designed it to do so.

You can show updates in a live tile with this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Live-Tiles-575b1d66

Also look at Windows Azure Mobile Services: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/